# inserting php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Its my first time using php and mysql together. Here's my database's script:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Alinfo_Express` ;
USE `Alinfo_Express` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Alinfo_Express`.`Categorias` (
  `idCategoria` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `descricao` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCategoria`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Alinfo_Express`.`Produtos` (
  `idProduto` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `descricao` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `precoUnidade` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `qtdEstocada` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `emDestaque` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
  `idCategoria` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProduto`),
  INDEX `fk_Produtos_Categorias1_idx` (`idCategoria` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Produtos_Categorias1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idCategoria`)
    REFERENCES `Alinfo_Express`.`Categorias` (`idCategoria`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Alinfo_Express`.`Usuarios` (
  `idUsuario` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `sexo` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `cpf` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `rg` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `CEP` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `bairro` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `cidade` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `estado` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `senha` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUsuario`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Alinfo_Express`.`Compra` (
  `idCompra` INT NOT NULL,
  `valor` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  `tipoPagamento` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dataCompra` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `idUsuario` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `idProduto` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCompra`),
  INDEX `fk_Compra_Usuarios_idx` (`idUsuario` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Compra_Produtos1_idx` (`idProduto` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Compra_Usuarios`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idUsuario`)
    REFERENCES `Alinfo_Express`.`Usuarios` (`idUsuario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Compra_Produtos1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idProduto`)
    REFERENCES `Alinfo_Express`.`Produtos` (`idProduto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Here's my code:

```
$MySQLi->query("INSERT INTO Produtos (idProduto, nome, descricao, precoUnidade,qtdEstocada, emDestaque, idCategoria) VALUES ($cod, '$nome', '$desc', $preco,$qtd, $dest, '$url', $cat);");
```

I don't know why it isn't working out. There's a long time I don't work with databases, that maybe be my problem.

Comment: Based on what you've posted here, neither do we.

Comment: Is the query correct?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot describing my database's fields. I'll edit.

Comment: No idea. You haven't posted a schema nor any sample data, nor the surrounding PHP code, nor any PHP or MySQL errors.

Comment: In addition, I would suggest using MySQLi [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for more secure input.

Comment: You have seven columns in your query, but __eight__ values. You should check your MySQL calls for errors and log any error messages you get. It makes debugging a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of mistakes in your query. Try to execute in phpmyadmin. Try this one

```
$MySQLi->query("INSERT INTO Produtos (idProduto, nome, descricao, precoUnidade,qtdEstocada, emDestaque, idCategoria) VALUES ($cod, '$nome', '$desc', $preco, $qtd, $dest, '$url', $cat)");
```

It should work. In phpmyadmin, it will tell you error. Share it with us.

Comment: I didn't realize I had 8 values, but 7 columns. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try with this i hope it will work

```
$MySQLi->query("INSERT INTO Produtos (idProduto, nome, descricao, precoUnidade,qtdEstocada, emDestaque, idCategoria) VALUES ('".$cod."', '".$nome."', '".$desc.'", '".$preco."','".$qtd."', '".$dest."', '".$url."', '".$cat."')");
```